# HomebrewでRubyをインストールしたつもりが、バージョンが更新されていない

Tags: ruby, homebrew

下記コマンドを実行しても、`ruby -v`でRuby3.0.0に更新されていません。
`rbenv`は使わずに、brewのみでバージョン反映できますでしょうか。

```
homefolder@USER ~ % brew install ruby
Warning: ruby 3.0.0_1 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 3.0.0_1, run `brew reinstall ruby`
homefolder@USER ~ % ruby -v
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

brewでinstallできるRubyはkeg-onlyですので、PATHに自分で追加しないとダメですよ。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`で解決しました。